# Cannot resolve FragmentActivity, FragmentTransaction, and more in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, import

So basically, every time I import something in Android Studio, say for example...
`FragmentActivity`  and then try to use it, I just get the error:

```
Cannot Resolve Symbol "FragmentActivity"
```

Here is a full example...

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
...
public class ReminderEditActivity extends FragmentActivity {
}
```

Also, Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.baconstripe.justanapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
   }
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Android Studio doesn't let me use many of the things I import. Please help!

Comment: Share your app gradle file

Comment: Did you install android support library?

Comment: @prudhvi Yes, I have installed, and recently updated the support library.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html Try this

Comment: I think you added v7 dependency in gradle and trying to use v4 support library.

Comment: Okay, I have fixed `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction` by changing them from `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` to `android.app.Fragment`. But strangely FragmentActivity still will not work.

Comment: Download appcompat library v4 and try again

Comment: So...FragmentActivity is in the appcompat library, yes?

Answer (score 2):

simply try deleting "/.idea/libraries" from main folder. then sync project again.

Comment: I tried to delete /build folder and also "File > Invalidate caches / restart ..." option, but only the aforementioned approach worked for me.

Comment: For me only clicking "File > Invalidate caches / restart ..." in IntelliJ did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the appcompat library into your project.

First, From SDK Manager, you install or update '**Android support library**' to the latest version.

Next, from `build.gradle`, add to dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"
}
```

Follow this link for detail:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: You need ```compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:25.0.1'``` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

Try using buildToolsVersion that will match the compileSdkVersion or higher.

Note: This is just a suggestion, hope it helps.